# How to deploy a .Net Core 2.1 application after upgrading from 1.1?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

We had a web application on .Net Core 1.1 hosted in a IIS server, and we used to published it Release and Portable and worked fine, just copy the contents and that's it.

But we have updated the app to .Net Core 2.1 and we have tried publishing Framework-dependant or Self-contained and many configurations but when we copy the contents on the IIS (we have changed nothing on the IIS) and run the app, it doesn't work.

We are interns and don't have much expertise or knowledge on the matter.

Comment: I did exactly that, and it worked pretty much directly so I don't think there is anything fundamentally wrong with your workflow, using the content of the folder in which you are publishing your app as an IIS application should be valid. Few suggestions: I/ have you installed the proper runtime on your server with the hosting bundle (it does the link between IIS and .NET Core) from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1 II/ If you go in the folder in which you have published and run "dotnet run" in a shell, what do you get? Is it properly running?

Comment: there are some big changes from 1.1 to 2.1, so you must be careful to follow the tutorial on how to do it. This must be done for your asp.net core app as well as enityframework core implementations that could have changed.

Comment: "we have changed nothing on the IIS" is completely wrong, as .NET Core 2.1 requires ANCM upgrade. If you are not certain what you should look for, run a report to reveal the essentials, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

are you familiar with Docker ? 
i use docker to build and publish my app, and here is the syntax

```
FROM ubuntu
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore

WORKDIR youre-app-main-project
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/app-name.dll"]
```

basicaly it means -

restore packages

> dotnet restore

publish to out directory

> dotnet publish -c Release -o out

run the app -

> dotnet out/app-name.dll

the app should be app and running (use [docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) for bonus points :-) )